# Python: swap two elements and keep the position of other special characters in a list?

Tags: python

### *Source data*

```
lst = [1, '^', 3, 5, '!', 'a', '%', 'b', '.', 12, '*']
```

### Desired Result:

```
[12, '^', 'b', 'a', '!', 5, '%', 3, '.', 1, '*']
```

### Questions:

I want to swap two elements and keep the position of the special characters in a list.

Just swap 1 and 12, 3 and b, 5 and a. (I want to have a better efficiency)

### *At the same time to traversing the list from the left and right and if the two elements are not special characters, the two elements will be swapped places ?*

Comment: Do you know the positions of the elements you want to swap?

Comment: what is the expected output if lst = [1, '^', 3, 5, '!', 'a', '%', 'b', '.', 12, 11, '*'] ? Your request on how to swap is not clear since you exchange the first and last values in your second example ....

Comment: The sum of letters and Numbers should be even.

Comment: lst = [1, '^', 3, 5, '!', 'a', '%', 'b', '.',11, '*'], expected result:  [11, '^', 'b', 'a', '!', 5, '%', 3, '.',1, '*']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach produces the result that you expect:

```
import string

lst = [1, '^', 3, 5, '!', 'a', '%', 'b', '.', 12, '*']

# i = Start_Position, j = End_Position
i, j = 0, len(lst)-1

# Traverse while Start_Position < End_Position
while i < j:
   # Swap values at Start_Position and End_Position if not special characters and update indexes
   if str(lst[i]) not in string.punctuation and str(lst[j]) not in string.punctuation:
     lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
     i += 1
     j -= 1
   # Decrease End_Position as special character found
   elif str(lst[i]) not in string.punctuation and str(lst[j]) in string.punctuation:
     j -= 1
   # Increase Start_Position as special character found
   elif str(lst[i]) in string.punctuation and str(lst[j]) not in string.punctuation:
     i += 1
   # Both values are special characters , update indexes
   else:
     i += 1
     j -= 1

print(lst)
```

> ```
> Input : [1, '^', 3, 5, '!', 'a', '%', 'b', '.', 12, '*']
>
> output: [12, '^', 'b', 'a', '!', 5, '%', 3, '.', 1, '*']
> ```

Comment: If we assume a function `isSpecial`, then I'd write that as `if !isSpecial(lst[i]) and !isSpecial(lst[j]): <as before> else: if isSpecial(lst[i]): i+=1 if isSpecial(lst[j]) j-= 1`

Comment: Thanks you very much, by now I have understood it !

Comment: @binbjz commented the solution code, the logic is simple, i have 2 indexes one at start and other at end, update indexes and swap based on conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. The main idea is to swap a sublist of only non-special characters and then fill the output list preserving the position of the special characters.

Input:

```
lst = [1, '^', 3, 5, '!', 'a', '%', 'b', '.', 12, '*']
```

Find the position of special characters:

```
import string
spec_pos = [idx for idx, el in enumerate(lst) if str(el) in string.punctuation]
```

Get the non-special values:

```
to_swap = [el for idx, el in enumerate(lst) if str(el) not in string.punctuation]
```

Define generic function to swap elements in list, using recursion:

```
def rec_swap(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l
    if len(l)==2:
        l[0], l[1] = l[1], l[0]
        return l
    else:
        return [l[-1]] + rec_swap(l[1:-1]) + [l[0]]
```

Swap elements:

```
swapped = rec_swap(sublist)
```

Create the output list:

```
out = []
_ = [out.append(swapped.pop(0)) if idx not in spec_pos else out.append(lst[idx]) for idx, el in enumerate(lst)]
```

This gives the expected output:

```
out
Out[60]: [12, '^', 'b', 'a', '!', 5, '%', 3, '.', 1, '*']
```